# Windows Server 2012 default desktop size

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, screen-resolution

I am using Windows Server 2012 r2 Datacentre edition running on an Azure virtual machine and I have come across a strange behaviour that hopefully someone can help me understand.

Put simply, when I use [AutoLogon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to ensure that a desktop exists for a particular user after restart, the desktop size appears to always be 1024x768 - I have attempted to change this using a multitude of routes including code but whichever way I change the resolution the method/api call/powershell cmdlet always appears to succeed but then on subsequent queries it's back to 1024x768. I first though that this was some default imposed by Windows when there is no display driver but after writing an app that enumerates supported display modes it returns a lot more *supported* resolutions. What's more bizarre is that if I use a remote desktop tool and set the resolution to something like 1920x1080 then the desktop is resized and even after the remote session is finished, queries for the desktop size now return the new resolution of 1920x1080... until the VM restarts.

I have spent a while now researching this phenomena to no avail - manually  changing every instance of 1024 and 768 in the registry doesn't no anything either.

Does anyone have any idea how I would change the *default* desktop size for a user when there is no display device and where this 1024x768 "magic" resolution comes from?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers so far and although I appreciate them I am already pretty certain that this isn't going to be resolved with a simple reg hack or startup tool (mainly because I've already tried them) - I am pretty sure the problems lies in the fact that there is a display driver (Hyper-V Video) but no display device

Thanks

Comment: are we talking about rdp here?

Comment: not really... it's actually the size of the desktop _before_ rdp - after an rdp session has started then all bets are off and you have a known resolution

Comment: What is it that you actually want to accomplish? Set a default resolution for RDP server side?

Comment: I would like to set the "screen resolution" for a user that is logged on automatically _without rdp_

Comment: Have you tried to do Set-DisplayResolution in the login script of the user?

Comment: Yes, it seems to succeed, but subsequent queries for the resolution return 1024x768

Answer (score 0):

You can run regedit.exe on your Server in an cmd and search for that registry entries.

To change the resolution, you need to look under \Video and find the right display GUID and then modify the resolution values:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\" & sDisplayGUID & "\0000\DefaultSettings.XResolution

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\" & sDisplayGUID & "\0000\DefaultSettings.YResolution

Hope that helps you.

Comment: When you say "find the right display GUID".... there is no display device

Comment: Hey sry about that, but which powershell scripts or commands u have used already? Maybe this one can help you: C:\> Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1200 -Force

Comment: Tried it... again, it seems to succeed but then `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight` returns 1024x768 again

Comment: Here is an Link to an identical question from the social.msdn.microsoft.com website https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1c215514-aeef-41d9-b47b-5c838a0bf83f/how-to-change-the-vm-default-screen-resolution?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Didn't work :( ... interestingly though I do have two Guids under which there is "0000" - I set the keys in one of them (which didn't work even though after a restart the values have persisted), the other one tells me I don't have permissions to set a value (regit as admin running from _the_ admin account)

Comment: Is there an option like Enhanced Session Mode in Azure? When there is an option like that, then disable this and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using AutoLogon, there is an old program called "resswitch" that will change resolution on logon.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/resswitch.aspx

It is ancient and I don't remember using it since XP days.  There is an alternative called "displaychanger" (http://12noon.com/?page_id=80) that is free for education but otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go but I don't hold out much hope considering all this tool does is call `EnumDisplaySettings` and then `ChangeDisplaySettings` - both of which I have already tried... EnumDisplaySettings returns good values but ChangeDisplaySettings does nothing